# Adding icon to each element in resource list (fullcalendar)

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

A controller in my Laravel 7 webapp gives me the resource feed for my fullcalender v5. It worked great until I tried to add an icon to each cell in the resource list. I tried different approaches but can't get the HTML displayed as HTML, it just prints the whole line `<?php echo "<i class="material-icons">edit</i>" ?>` to the cells in the resource list. How can I pass the HTML to FullCalendar to have it printed as HTML output? I don't want to do it by `resourceLabelContent`, because the controller manages the resources.

Code from my controller:

```
    public function resourceFeedProcessplan(Request $request)
    {
(...)
      $data = [];
      $map = $processes->map(function($items){
        $data['id'] = $items->id;
        $data['title'] = $items->title.' ('.$items->id.')'.'<?php echo "<i class="material-icons">edit</i>" ?>'; // HTML part not rendered as HTML by FullCalendar.
        return $data;
      }); 
      return $map;
    }
```

Comment: "I don't want to do it by resourceLabelContent, because the controller manages the resources"...sure, but in this case you're just adding the same static HTML to every resource. So actually I can't see a specific reason why it would be a problem to do that with resourceLabelContent - the controller code isn't varying the HTML output.

Comment: This edit button is just a simplified test to see if HTML is shown in the calendar. Lateron, there will be id-specific buttons for editing and deletion. But that's not the issue.

Comment: Ok. For future reference it's usually better to put a realistic example in your questions, then people (like me!) don't come along and go "there's no need to do it that way", and instead they can focus on your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never put HTML directly into the "title" property of a resource, fullCalendar will always treat it as text.

I suggest putting the required HTML for each resource into a custom property of the resource, and then use the `resourceLabelContent` callback to inject that as HTML into the DOM element being constructed by fullCalendar.

Something like this:

```
resourceLabelContent: function (arg)
{
  return { html: arg.resource.title + " " + arg.resource.extendedProps.html };
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzqrNze

P.S. Your PHP is faulty as well - you've put `<?php` tags into a string literal, which makes no sense. They won't be executed as PHP, so the tags will be sent to the browser as-is and will screw up the HTML. Just use put the data into your variable directly like any normal string.

e.g.

```
$map = $processes->map(function($items){
    $data['id'] = $items->id;
    $data['title'] = $items->title.' ('.$items->id.')';
    $data['html'] = '<i class="material-icons">edit</i>';
    return $data;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. By the way: Is it possible to put HTML to the `resourceAreaHeaderContent` field?

Comment: Yes, why not? As is clear from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-area-header-render-hooks), it's a Content Injection Input just the same as resourceLabelContent is.